# CSS Animating two halves of a picture to meet in the middle (responsive)

Tags: html, css, animation

So I have this problem where I need to make an animation with CSS where two halves of a picture are drawn on seperate responsive canvases, they start from the sides of the page, then meet in the middle of the page, then go back to the sides of the page again and this loops. I will try to demonstrate this with a picture:

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai2qV.png)

[Canvases meet in the middle like this then return to initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsof9.png)

So now my state is this: The pictures move but they move to the wrong position. This is what I have in the keyframes:

```
@keyframes leftslide {

to {
    margin-left:50%;
}


}

@keyframes rightslide {   

to {
    margin-right:50%;
}

}
```

So this almost works, but the margin pushes the pictures by 50% from the side of the screen, so the left image goes too far to the right by its own width and the right picture goes too far to the left by its own width.

So to fix this, while keeping the animation responsive I would need something that works like this:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - WidthOfTheCanvas);

margin-right: calc(50% - WidthOfTheCanvas);
```

However I have no idea how to acquire the width of the canvas I'm moving so that I can reduce the right amount of margin.

So without the solution to this my pictures move too much and end up overlapping eachother in the middle.

Is there a way to find out the current size of the element I'm moving or should I do this by using something else than margin? I've been struggling with this for a few hours and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
[enter image description here][3]

Comment: Can you provide everything you have please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Experiment with value to get the right result, but most likely you are looking for 50% / -50%;